# Docker nancy - no route to host

Tags: docker, nancy

I have a docker container which hosts a web api written in Nancy. Here is the exception that occurs after a web request is made when the container is first fired up:

```
    4/22/2016 2:40:50 PM  at API.SearchModule+<SearchModule>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.Object _) <0x41380aa0 + 0x00850> in <filename unknown>:0 
    4/22/2016 2:40:50 PM  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:CallSite.Target (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Func`2<object, object>,object)
    4/22/2016 2:40:50 PM  at Nancy.Routing.Route+<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3 (System.Object parameters, CancellationToken context) <0x4133d350 + 0x00166> in <filename unknown>:0 
    4/22/2016 2:40:50 PM2016-04-22 13:40:50,177 ERROR: System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (No route to host) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host
    4/22/2016 2:40:50 PM  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) <0x41374320 + 0x001b8> in <filename unknown>:0 
    4/22/2016 2:40:50 PM  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) <0x41372b50 + 0x00609> in <filename unknown>:0
```

The app queries elasticsearch when a web request is made, initially I thought it was blowing up because it couldn't find elastic (another docker container), however this doesn't seem to be the case as locally if I stop elastic the api will continue serving requests albeit it will throw exceptions. Once elastic is back online, the api continues to serve requests this time without exceptions.

The bizarre thing is if the docker container is restarted again the web requests against the api are successful at querying elastic.

Is there anyway I can replicate this issue locally so I can attempt to work on a fix? I had thought that if I run it locally with elastic offline I would get the same error, however this doesn't seem to be the case which makes me think it's some sort of network connectivity issue.

What do you guys think it could be?

Comment: Are you using docker links feature to link app and elasticsearch container? If yes, how do you connect to elastic via env vars, or hostname?

Comment: What version of docker are you using? On which host?

Comment: Post contents of compose file (if using one) and the commands you're using to run the containers.

Comment: @jazgot I'm using docker links and connecting via env vars.

Comment: There is one catch with using links, maybe this is your case: when you start app container with link to elastic it will be given current ip of elastic and this ip will be saved within app container. If ip of elastic container changes then your app won't be able to connect to elastic (because link is kinda static, and won't be updated).

Answer (score 1):

It is a DNS problem. Your docker container is unable to resolve the IP address for the provided URL (Host).

Take a look to the `--dns` option (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) or amend the `resolv.conf` file inside your docker image/container.

Comment: Thank you, why is it that it works when it's restarted if it's a DNS issue?

Comment: I restarted and it solved my issue you are life savior